# Aliasing in Qt Items?

Tags: qgraphicsview, antialiasing, qgraphicsitem, qpixmap

How come this happens to my QPixmap painted in a QGraphicsView?
It has 0.8 opacity added by code.

[image]

It´s a PNG image. The original looks like this:

[image]

I see this kind of strange flickering that stays the same depending on the height of the QMainWindow. When i resize it, some of the pixmaps get disorted.